# Iterate on an array starting from a specific index

Tags: ruby

I want to start iterating over an array from a specific index. How can I do that?

```
myj.each do |temp| 
  ...
end
```

Comment: Will that specific index always be same?

Comment: yes. it will be allways the same

Comment: Then you got the answer below.

Answer (score 15):

Do the following:

```
your_array[your_index..-1].each do |temp| 
  ###
end
```

Comment: but I dont understand the issue of -1. Can you explain it?

Comment: @marius_ll `-1` indicates the *index of last element* in the array

Comment: yes, so basically it is a range starting from specified index to end of array.

Answer (score 9):

More idiomatic would be to use [`Enumerable#drop`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-drop):

```
myj.drop(index).each do |temp| 
  ###
end
```

Comment: that's cool too, thanx..but it needs to specify number of elements than index.

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon Number of elements to drop is **literally** the same as an index to start with.

Comment: yeah, however i meant w.r.t range where you have flexibility i.e. `[1..-1]` is different than `[1...-1]`. if you consider mine and yours solution in this case then both are same.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a simple for loop. Assuming that the array is arr, start index is "start" and the end index is "end"

```
for i in start..end do
  #Access array items by arr[i]
end
```